# XSL back button

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm not an expert in this area. I did some searching but didn't find exactly what I'm looking for. Hopefully it's fairly simple.

I'm working on a software control system that has a built-in web server. There are some points during navigation of this system that the only way out is to use the web browsers back button (unfortunate, I know).

For the operators using this, they usually do all their navigation on screen, and to suddenly be presented with a display that has "no way out" could cause confusion.

I'd like to modify the `layout.xsl` file to add a back button. (If it matters, it's only ever going to be Internet Explorer, as the system is based on ActiveX.)

Here are the relevant parts of the file:

```
<table id="Menu" class="Header" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="100%">
      <table class="menuBar" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr height="0">

          <xsl:for-each select="Links/Link">
            <xsl:if test="text() != 'Lists'">
              <xsl:if test="text() != 'Database'">
                <xsl:if test="text() != 'Favorites'">
                  <xsl:if test="text() != 'Log Off'">
                    <xsl:if test="text() != 'Help'">
                      <xsl:call-template name="Button">
                        <xsl:with-param name="href" select="@href"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text()"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="last" select="boolean( position() = count( ../Link ) )"/>
                      </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:if>
                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>

          <th class="rightbar" align="right" valign="top"/>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<xsl:template name="Button">
  <xsl:param name="href"/>
  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:param name="last"/>

  <th width="auto" height="20" class="deselected" valign="center">
    <xsl:element name="a">
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="$href"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </th>
  <th width="5" class="deselected" valign="middle">
    <img src="/file/images/submenumid.png" width="5" height="20"/>
  </th>
</xsl:template>
```

You'll see that the table calls the button template several times. If you're confused about these lines,

```
<xsl:if test="text() != 'xxxx'">
```

those were added by me to filter out existing buttons I didn't want displayed.

What I'm hoping for is to have a similar template called `back button` that will send a back command to internet explorer. I would then call the `back button` template first so that it's the left-most item.

Thanks in advance, let me know if any additional info is required!

Comment: I should note that the params are all coming from outside of the code sample. That really shouldn't matter for this question though.

Comment: There is an `and`, even in XSLT 1.0. There's no need for those nested `xsl:if` elements!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <table id="Menu" class="Header" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="100%">
                <table class="menuBar" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr height="0">
                        <xsl:call-template name="Button">
                            <xsl:with-param name="href">javascript:history.back()</xsl:with-param>
                            <xsl:with-param name="text">Go Back</xsl:with-param>
                            <xsl:with-param name="last" select="false()"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>

                        <xsl:for-each select="Links/Link">
                            <xsl:if test="text() != 'Lists'
                            and text() != 'Database'
                            and text() != 'Favorites'
                            and text() != 'Log Off'
                            and text() != 'Help'">
                                <xsl:call-template name="Button">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="href" select="@href"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text()"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="last" select="boolean( position() = count( ../Link ) )"/>
                                </xsl:call-template>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>

                        <th class="rightbar" align="right" valign="top"/>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This is the finalized code. I cleaned up the many 'if' statements thanks to Borodins suggestion.
I also added a new call to Button template with the history.back() link instead of adding a new template.

Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template name="BackButton">
  <xsl:param name="last"/>

  <xsl:call-template name="Button">
    <xsl:with-param name="href" select="javascript:window.history.back()"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="Go back"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="last" select="$last"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
<xsl:template/>
```